# Как инициализировать программно кнопку в Андроид?

Tags: java, android

Я описываю метод обработки при нажатии на кнопку в одном классе, так как одна и та же кнопка будет в разных активити. Чтобы не дублировать код я вынес его в отдельный класс, но этот класс не наследует от `AppCompatActivity`.

Как инициализировать кнопку в этом классе? Я хочу вызвать функцию `findViewById()`, но она не работает.

Comment: В вопрос стоит добавить [минимальный и полный пример](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) кода. Достаточно сложно обсуждать код без кода. Если так сходу: можно либо передавать в класс кнопки уже полученную `View`, либо код, связанный с `View`, оставить в `Activity`.

Comment: Решение проблемы в 3-х буквах. OOП

Answer (score 3):

Если кнопка в разных экранах то от установки обработчика в каждом экране никуда не деться. Можно свести к минимуму дублирующий код, если вынести независимую от конкретного экрана работу в отдельный класс. Например так:

Класс "workera" с общей логикой

```
public class MyWorker {

    public void doSomeWork(){
        //some work
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{
    public void onClick(View view) {
        MyWorker worker = new MyWorker();
        worker.doSomeWork();
    }
});
```

Либо можно воспользоваться инструментом [Data Bindind](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/data-binding/guide.html), реализовать в классе-обработчике требуемое поведение и устанавливать вызов метода из этого обработчика через файлы разметки.

Пример Handler'a:

```
public class MyHandlers {
    public void onClickMyButton(View view) { ... }
}
```

Установка через файл разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <data>
       <variable name="handlers" type="com.example.Handlers"/>
   </data>
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@{user.lastName}"
           android:onClick="@{handlers.onClickMyButton}"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Более подробнее про `Data Binding` и о том как его завести у себя в проекте читайте в [официальном гайде](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/data-binding/guide.html).

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById()` - такой метод есть только у чайлдов `Activity` и `View`. Можно, конечно, передать в твой класс вьюху, на которой расположена кнопка. Но, это вызовет утечку памяти, т.к. класс будет хранить ссылку на context вьюхи. Лучше так не делать и переопределить на каждом экране `onClick()` для кнопки.